# Possibilities when trying to access an instance attribute?

Tags: python, attributes, getter-setter, instance-variables

I would like to find an exhaustive lookup operations made by the Python interpreter when trying to access an instance attribute or setting it to a new value.

I know several things about it by reading and experimenting:

- When there is a `property` or a descriptor in the class body, it's used before anything
- When there is the same attribute (with the same name I mean) in the `__dict__` of the instance and the `__dict__` of the class, the instance's one is used first
- When the `__gettatribute__` and the `__getattr__` are both define in the class body, `__gettatribute__` is used first since `__getattr__` is only being called when the attribute isn't found elsewhere

But I was wondering about some limit cases...
Can somebody give a explanation of all possibilities?

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Comment: If you search you should find explanations, here and elsewhere.

Comment: Have you read the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html)?